# Why does changing the order of array results in Time Limit Exceeded?

Tags: java, arrays, backtracking, knights-tour

This is the classic "Knight Tour" Problem. I have used x_mov[] and y_mov[] to define the next co-ordinates the knight will take.
The problem is, when I rearrange the arrays x_mov[] and y_mov[] (simultaneously), the program doesn't give an output and results in TLE. 
But when the order is in a direction from 0 degree to 360 degree, the output is correct.

```
static int N = 8;

public static void main(String args[]){
    solveKTP();
}

static void solveKTP(){
    int sol[][] = new int[N][N];

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(int j=0; j<N;j ++)
            sol[i][j] = -1;

    sol[0][0] = 0;

    //This ORDER Does not give the result

    //int x_mov[] = {2, 2,-2,-2, 1,-1, 1,-1};
    //int y_mov[] = {1,-1, 1,-1, 2, 2,-2,-2};

    //This Order GIVES the correct result
    //Notice how the direction changes from 1st to 2nd to 3rd to 4th quadrant.

    int x_mov[] = {2, 1,-1,-2, -2, -1, 1, 2};
    int y_mov[] = {1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2,-2,-1};

    if(backtrack(0,0,sol,x_mov,y_mov,1))
        printSol(sol);
    else
        System.out.println("Not Possible");

}


static boolean backtrack(int x ,int y, int sol[][], int x_mov[], int y_mov[], int movi){

    if(movi == N*N) {
        //System.out.println("Here");
        return true;
    }

    for( int k = 0; k<8; k++){
         int next_x = x + x_mov[k];
         int next_y = y + y_mov[k];

        if(isSafe(next_x,next_y, sol)){
            sol[next_x][next_y] = movi;

            if(backtrack(next_x,next_y, sol, x_mov, y_mov,movi+1))
                return true;
            else
                sol[next_x][next_y] = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int sol[][]){
    return (x>=0 && x<N && y>=0 && y<N && sol[x][y]==-1);
}

static void printSol(int sol[][]){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< N ; j++)
            System.out.print(sol[i][j]+ " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I have searched for the answer but couldn't find it. I'll be grateful if anybody could explain me why is that happening.
Please comment is you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Have observed same, Checking values randomly will cause too many backtracks due to huge number of possibilities appx. 19,000,000 billions possible tours, It becomes time consuming however it should give result in some time.